# What technologies exist for client- and serverside debugging for RIA development

Tags: javascript, debugging, ria

I'd be interested to know in what the debugging approaches for RIA-development are.
In particular i am curious whether there are tools which provide a kind of holistic debugging approach for the client and server side at the same time.

From what I've read you can do something like that with GWT using the hosted mode or in ASP.Net where the server side breakpoint gets [somehow mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx) to the client side (I haven't tried it).

Is there a method to debug client and server side integrated for more classical approaches with HTML+CSS+Javascript as the client technology and a separate server backend (with no restriction to its language).

I guess this would be a very specific implementation, since there is usually also a framework-specific way to communicate with the backend.

Maybe i am just ignorant to the restrictions and reasons as to why such an implementation wouldn't be sensible, which would then also interest me.

Answer (score 1):

XDebug has [IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632369/cant-get-php-debugging-to-work-with-komodo-but-im-almost-there) and [browser extensions](http://derickrethans.nl/new-xdebug-helper.html). [Watir on Rails](https://github.com/chip/watir-on-rails) is a good solution as well.  For a language agnostic solution, [Komodo IDE](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/) + [Stackato](http://www.activestate.com/stackato/compare-with-cloud-foundry) + [Feedhenry](https://www.feedhenry.com/mobile-application-platform/) would provide the most flexibility.