# Can't get PHP debugging to work with Komodo (but I'm almost there!)

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging, komodo

I posted about this a week or so ago but since then I've done some further troubleshooting so I thought it was worth posting again:

I'm trying to set up PHP debugging in Komodo 7, using the Xdebug extension that ships with Komodo. The extension seems to be working fine, and Komodo responds when I try and start a debug session.

However, Komodo doesn't let me step-through my PHP code; instead it just runs through the code in a pane in the bottom-right of the Komodo window.

For the record, I don't have any Mapped URIs.

I'd really appreciate any help anyone's able to offer on this as I've got a website I need to debug for a great non-profit and this problem is preventing me from working.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps listed at: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/debugphp.html? In addition, what happens when you set a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I have. If I open a .php page in Firefox with XDebug switched on, Komodo recognises that I want to start a debugging session. However, rather than stepping through the code for that .php page and stopping at any breakpoints, Komodo just runs through all of the code in the page in a pane towards the bottom-left of the Komodo window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ran this past Activestate's tech support on IRC (#Komodo on irc.mozilla.org) who were really helpful. We couldn't work out what the problem was, though, so I ended up uninstalling XAMPP and Komodo, reinstalling both, and then following the instructions in the Komodo docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [debugger connection preferences](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#DebuggerConnection) to change the port that Komodo listens to from the default value of 9000 to [a system provided free port](http://community.activestate.com/node/7848), 8080, or whatever port your remote host or localhost is running.

Comment: The link is to an XML file which I don't understand.  Second link is 404.