# Komodo IDE Xdebug remote debugging URI Mapping not working

Tags: php, macos, xdebug, remote-debugging, komodo

I have remote debugging working with Xdebug, which works properly (I guess) when I use MacGDBp as a debugging tool. I've got Komodo 5 hooked up to listen on port 9000, and when I launch an Xdebug session remotely, Komodo throws up a dialog for URI Mapping.

the URI given is `file://IP.of.host.machine/path/to/my/project`
The empty field is asking for "Maps to:" which I attempt to point to a local directory. I click the button "Local", and put it in /Users/myname/Documents/xdebug

However, when I hit enter, the "Maps to:" field is emptied and I'm faced with a continuous loop of URI Mapping dialogs.

What could be the issue? I've already changed the permissions on the local "Maps to:" directory with a `chmod -R 777 /xdebug`

I'm not sure what else would be the issue.

What can I do to get a local map for debugging in Komodo 5, and / or what is another solution to being able to step through and watch variable values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get PHP debugging to work with Komodo (but I'm almost there!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632369/cant-get-php-debugging-to-work-with-komodo-but-im-almost-there)